# How to reliably use run-python with venv in buffer-env?

Tags: python, buffer-local

I have a python project using venv under `PROJECT_FOLDER/.venv`. I wrote an `.envrc` file there to activate the environment. `buffer-env-describe` seems to know about it. However, when I am in a python script in my project I cannot start a python interpretter (run-python). It says it can't find python3:

```
start-process: Searching for program: No such file or directory, python3
```

Nevertheless, when looking at `(getenv "PATH")` in that buffer I see the venv path at the front.

What is the disconnect happening here? I remember in the past this was working. Although, I didn't understand why. I'm not really sure what changed. All I know is that I have had it configured through an `.envrc` file:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Activate the python environment
. .venv/bin/activate
```

Then in my `custom.el` I see that .envrc file declared safe to execute. What step am I missing?

Comment: mekeor on the #emacs IRC channel informed me of the `inheritenv` package. Installing that and requiring it made run-python discover the python3 executable.